# HTTPService/ResultEvent with Flex 3.2 versus Flex >= 3.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, httpservice

through a design decission or what-so-ever Adobe changed the content of the ResultEvent fired by a HTTPService Object.

Take a look at following example:

```
var httpService:HTTPService = myHTTPServices.getResults();
httpService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,resultHandler);
httpService.send();

/**
 * Handels the login process
 */
function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    // get http service
    var httpService = (event.target as HTTPService);

    // do something
}
```

It works like a charm with Flex 3.2. But when I try to compile it with Flex 3.5 or Flex 4.0 *event.target as HTTPService* is null.

I figured out that event.target is now an instance of *HTTPOperation*. That is interesting because I can't find *HTTPOperation* in the langref. However, I think what Flash Builder's debugger means is *mx.rpc.http.Operation*.

The debugger also shows that *event.target* has a private attribute *httpService* which is the instance I expected to get with *event.target*. But it's private, so *event.target.httpService* doesn't work.

If I only want to remove the EventListener I can cast *event.target* as *EventDispatcher*. But I need to use methods from *HTTPService*.

So: How can I get the *HTTPService* instance from the ResultEvent?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

J.

Answer (score 2):

It is useful to go through the source if you get into this. On OS X the `rpc` classes are here: `/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2/sdks/3.4.1/frameworks/projects/rpc/src`

Inside `mx.rpc.http.HTTPService` there is indeed an inner-class named `HTTPOperation`.
It extends `mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation` which in turn extends `mx.rpc.AbstractOperation`. Inside `AbstractOperation` is a getter method `get service` which looks to return what you need.

Since `HTTPService` is an inner-class it is effectively private so you'll need to cast to an `AbstractOperation` (either `mx.rpc.http.AbstractOperation` or `mx.rpc.AbstractOperation`).

So something like:

```
function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    // get the operation
    var operation:AbstractOperation = AbstractOperation(event.target);

    // get http service
    var httpService:HTTPService = HTTPService(operation.service);
}
```

**edit:** I take it back! Looks like Adobe is sending `null` for the service when it calls the super when constructing the HTTPOperation. The HTTPService is therefore only cached in the private variable `httpService`. I have no idea why they hide it from you but it looks like you'll have to keep your own reference around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll wait for any more thoughts on that but I think I have to keep my own references around. This will be lots of work though!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem for myself.
There are some properties in `HTTPService` that are available from `AbstractOperation`. For example, I use property `request` which is an Object:

```
myService.request["service"] = myService;
```

And later, when I get Event which has `HTTPOperation` in `event.currentTarget`, I get my `HTTPService` in such way:

```
 var eventService : HTTPService = HTTPService( AbstractOperation( event.currentTarget ).request["service"] );
```